# extract json data from the string contains json data

Tags: java, string

I am new to java
my string contains : "{'message': 'hello'}";

I want to convert above string to JSON data  that gives 'message' key gives 'hello' as value. can any one please help me out ?.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're far more likely to get an answer if you show you have tried anything before posting your question.

Comment: yes i tried , but failed , actually that data comes from server in  string format contains JSON data. I can't handle the JSON data directly, so i convert it to string format. from that i want to extract the actual JSON data.

Comment: Use one of the many json libraries that are listed at json.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [json.org library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107), and do something like this:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String message = "{'message': 'hello'}";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(message);

        System.out.println(json.get("message"));
    }
}
```